# highlight span per div tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Got this multiple choices examination..
I am in a part where the examinee choosing the correct answer,
I am doing it fine but the problem is when i add the number two question..
which the highlight answer changing also into another div. Any logic or other way without changing the HMTL.........................................

Here's my code

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".__QNnChoiceContainer").forEach((chosenAns) => {
  $(chosenAns).on('click', '.__choicesMLExam', function () {
    $('.__QNnChoiceContainer .__choicesMLExam.__theAnswerMLExam').removeClass('__theAnswerMLExam');
    $(this).addClass('__theAnswerMLExam');
  });
})
```

```css
.__theAnswerMLExam{
  position:relative;
}
.__theAnswerMLExam:before{
  content:"";
  background-color:#d2ffd2;
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  filter:url(#marker-shape);
  top:0.1em;
  padding:0 0.25em;
}

#QuestionMLExam{
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ChoicesExam{
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 45%;
}
.__choicesMLExam{
  font-weight: normal !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}
.__QNnChoiceContainer{
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.__rightChoiceExamML, .__leftChoiceExamML{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.__wrapContainerExamML{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 75px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">1. What is the type of pin that has 3 swaged grooves at 120⁰ pitch along its side?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Taper Pin</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Dowel Pin</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Grooved Pin</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Knurled Pin</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">2. What is the type of pin that was used to control compression of part made with Plastic?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Taper Pin</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Dowel Pin</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Grooved Pin</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Knurled Pin</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">3. What is the Taper Ratio of a Taper Pin?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML"  class="__choicesMLExam">2:1</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">1:50</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">1:100</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">2:50</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target currently clicked question block. Then add/remove class for that question only.

Code Example:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.__choicesMLExam', function () {
  $(this).parents('.ChoicesExam').find('.__choicesMLExam').removeClass('__theAnswerMLExam');
  $(this).addClass('__theAnswerMLExam');
});
```

```css
.__theAnswerMLExam{
  position:relative;
}
.__theAnswerMLExam:before{
  content:"";
  background-color:#d2ffd2;
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  filter:url(#marker-shape);
  top:0.1em;
  padding:0 0.25em;
}

#QuestionMLExam{
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ChoicesExam{
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 45%;
}
.__choicesMLExam{
  font-weight: normal !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}
.__QNnChoiceContainer{
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.__rightChoiceExamML, .__leftChoiceExamML{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.__wrapContainerExamML{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 75px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">1. What is the type of pin that has 3 swaged grooves at 120⁰ pitch along its side?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Taper Pin</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Dowel Pin</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Grooved Pin</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Knurled Pin</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">2. What is the type of pin that was used to control compression of part made with Plastic?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Taper Pin</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Dowel Pin</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Grooved Pin</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">Knurled Pin</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="__QNnChoiceContainer">
  <label id="QuestionMLExam">3. What is the Taper Ratio of a Taper Pin?</label>
  <div class="ChoicesExam">
    <div class="__leftChoiceExamML">
      <label>a. <span id="choicesAExamML"  class="__choicesMLExam">2:1</span></label>
      <label>b. <span id="choicesBExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">1:50</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="__rightChoiceExamML">
      <label>c. <span id="choicesCExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">1:100</span></label>
      <label>d. <span id="choicesDExamML" class="__choicesMLExam">2:50</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```